# How can I do to color a rectangle when I click on it?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am programming using Python; more precisely, I am using the `Matplotlib` library to create two two rectangles.  What I would like is when I click on a rectangle the rectangle turns green. I do not know how to to this. Here is my code:

```py
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_rectangle():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 3))
    plt.axis('off')
    ax = plt.gca().axes
    rectangles = []
    rectangles.append(ax.add_patch(Rectangle((29, 2), width=.8, height=.8,
                       color='gray', alpha=.3)))
    rectangles.append(ax.add_patch(Rectangle((14, 4), width=.8, height=.8,
                       color='gray', alpha=.3)))
    plt.xlim(1, 32)
    plt.ylim(1, 13)
    for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
        spine.set_visible(False)
    plt.tick_params(top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
    plt.show()
    def onclick(event):
        # when we click on a rectangle the rectangle becomes green
        pass
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", onclick)


plot_rectangle()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like your `onclick` event is actually being called. Probably should get that to print something and get it to work. Then you can store your `Rectangle()` elements as vars and modify the color property when you get the callback.

Comment: You need to put `plt.show()` after connecting the callback.

Comment: Thank you but what I want is  what I have to write into the function onclick(event) ?